# iOS do NSLog statements represent a security /privacy issue, or are they ignored by the system in 2018?

Tags: security, ios11, xcode9, nslog

I have an app that potentially prints sensitive information to console using NSLog. I'm not aware of the current status of NSLog and am looking to make a suggestion on whether this should be removed.

- Are NSLog statements visible in device logs when plugged into a computer?
- Can other apps read from the console/ NSLog?
- **Do NSLog statements with sensitive info (like keys or tokens) represent a security /privacy issue, or are they ignored by the system in 2018?**

My information is very outdated - around iOS 4 I could see my own NSLogs in the console and logs available from organizer>Devices>device logs. But recently it seems I'm only seeing the crash logs in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't prevent debugging your app on jailbroken device, so it's better to avoid output of sensitive information using `NSLog`.